# .Array Index Out Of Bounds Exception in for loop

Tags: java, arrays, loops

The Eclipse IDE complains about the for loop using/accessing the array of books being out of bounds. The line (19) it complains about is: 
        if (books[x] == null) {

I do not believe is the problem its complaining about as I have replaced that if code with many different things and it still complains. One line up is the first line of the for loop which is
        for (int x = 0; x < capacity ; ++x)

I have also triple checked the condition is right and it should be. capacity is 5 meaning the array of objects positions would be at 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 so starting x at 0 should be right from what I know about arrays.

Library Class (The one with the loop)

```
    package exercises;

    public class Library {
        private int capacity;
        private Book[] books = new Book[capacity];
        public Library(int capacity) {
            if (capacity > 1) {
                this.capacity = capacity;
            }
            else {
                this.capacity = 4;
            }
        }
        public boolean addBook(Book book) {
            int freeLocation = -1;
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            int notFreeLocation = -1;
            for (int x = 0; x < capacity ; ++x) {
                if (books[x] == null) { /*this is line 19*/
                    freeLocation = x;
                }
                else {
                    notFreeLocation = x;
                }
            }

            if (freeLocation == -1) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                books[freeLocation] = book;
                return true;
            }
        }
```

The Library App class

```
    package exercises;

    public class LibraryApp {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Library library = new Library(5);
            library.addBook(new Book("The Lord of the Rings", "J. R. R. Tolkien"));
            library.addBook(new Book("Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone", "J. K. Rowling"));
            library.addBook(new Book("1984", "George Orwell"));
            library.addBook(new Book("Where the Wild Things Are", "Maurice Sendak"));
            library.addBook(new Book("The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy", "Douglas Adams"));
            System.out.println(library);
            Book aBook = library.borrow("1984");
            System.out.println("Book borrowed: " + aBook);
        }

    }
```

I get the error 
                "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:        0
                    at exercises.Library.addBook(Library.java:19)
                    at exercises.LibraryApp.main(LibraryApp.java:8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When this is done in `Library`:

```
private int capacity;
private Book[] books = new Book[capacity];
```

the code in your constructor hasn't run yet (those initializations are inserted into your constructor at the very beginning [or just after `super()` in a subclass]). So `capacity` has its default value, `0`. **Later** you assign to `capacity`, but it's too late.

Instead:

```
public class Library {
    private int capacity;
    private Book[] books;                     // *** Don't initialize it here
    public Library(int capacity) {
        if (capacity > 1) {
            this.capacity = capacity;
        }
        else {
            this.capacity = 4;
        }
        this.books = new Book[this.capacity]; // *** Initialize it here
    }
```

But there's another useful thing to learn here. When looping through an array or similar, use the **array**'s knowledge of how big it is, not some other source of information (`capacity`). So:

```
for (int x = 0; x < this.books.length ; ++x) {
// -----------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Stick with the primary source of truth. :-) (In fact, you probably don't need your `capacity` instance member at all.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help T.J! This solved my problem. I struggled with the idea of object arrays and how they worked as well as not fully understanding constructors hence not understanding that capacity is 0 as I initialized it to early. 

Also in terms of using the "primary source of truth" I shall definitely do that in the future :D  You have helped a lot as my mid terms are coming up in a week and I am more then happy I figured this out now rather then in the test!

Answer (score 0):

You try to make an array with 0 (default int) size.
Move the

```
private Book[] books = new Book[capacity];
```

to constructor after assigning value to capacity.